# Tricky php class method default parameter syntax

Tags: php, class, default-value

I am having difficulty understanding the proper syntax for the second default value in the following method declaration statement. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
protected function load($columName = self::_tableIdName, $columnValue = self::_data->{self::_tableIdName}) 
{...}
```

Notes: `$_tableIdName` is a protected variable within the class;
`$_data` is a protected stdClass object within the class.
I am trying to make the default for `$columnValue` equal to the corresponding value from the internal `$_data` object.

Comment: FYI, did you mean `$columnName` as the first parameter to the load function? You put `$columName`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the defaults to null, then check for null in the function body. You are limited to using constants in the argument intializer.

Comment: Well that now that you say it, I guess that should have obvious. Thanks much.